# Diffeomorphism of product manifolds given diffeomorphisms on the factors.

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

Given $\mathcal{M} = \mathcal{M_1} \times \dots \times \mathcal{M_k}$ where $\mathcal{M_i}$ are smooth manifolds and $\phi_i:\mathcal{M_i} \to \mathcal{M_i}$ diffeomorphisms for each $i$.

Is $\phi: \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$ where $\phi = (\phi_1 , \dots , \phi_k) $ a diffeomorphism?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The answer to me seems like it obviously is. We could essentially just apply the definition of diffeomorphic and show that $\phi$ and it's inverse are differentiable. I've tried that and it seems to have worked.

But, I'm extremely new to these ideas and wanted to double check.

Comment: Then you should write here what your solution is and we can give you feedback. Indeed, it is not very hard, but very instructive.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer:

$\phi$ has derivative given by $\phi' : T\mathcal{M_1} \times \dots \times T\mathcal{M_k}$ where

$$
\phi' = (\phi'_1,\dots , \phi'_k)
$$

as each $\phi_i$ is diffeomorphic each $\phi'_i$ is continuous. Thus by the Characteristic Property of Product Topology $\phi'$ is also continuous.

The inverse is given by $\phi^{-1} = (\phi_1^{-1} , \dots , \phi_k^{-1})$. A similiar argument shows $\phi'^{-1}$ is continuous.

Thus $\phi$ is a differentiable function with differentiable inverse. So a diffeomorphism.